# Deleting many files except one type

Tags: shell-script, rm, latex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deleting all files in a folder except files X, Y, and Z](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7215/deleting-all-files-in-a-folder-except-files-x-y-and-z)

I am writing a script to compile many `.tex` files. After that, many auxiliaries files were created.

So, I would like to remove them at the end of the script. I tough to use `rm $file.xxx` but I would have to write all the extensions by hand, since that I want to keep my source file and the pdf output, so I can not use the * to delete all.

How to delete all the extensions except those with extension `.tex/.pdf`?

Thanks.

Comment: See the duplicate question. But I **do not recommend** doing it that way. You risk accidentally deleting an important file. It's better to enumerate the extensions to delete, that way if you forget one you won't lose data. Pass the `-f` option to `rm` so that it doesn't complain if there is no file with one of the extensions (`rm -f *.aux *.bbl *.blg *.idx *.ilg *.ind *.lof *.log *.lot *.toc` …).

Comment: @Gilles, thanks. Now I guess that it'll work. I didn't know about the `-f` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could just ignore the `rm` errors, but that's not elegant :).

Add a function like this to your ~/.bashrc:

```
 function cleantex () {
   find . -name "$1*" | grep -vP '.tex$|.pdf$' | while read -r i; do rm "$i"; done    
  }
```

You then call it with the (unique) beginning of your filename like so:

```
 $ cleantex mytexfile
```

It will delete all files in the given directory that start with `$file` and do not end in `.tex` or `.pdf`. The `$` makes sure the match is only at the end of the file, the extension. Otherwise it will ignore files like `footexfoo.aux` because the file name contains `tex`. You can add as many extensions to ignore as you want:

```
 function cleantex () {
       find . -name "$1*" | grep -vP '.tex$|.pdf$|.foo$|.bar$' | while read -r i; do rm "$i"; done    
      }
```

---

If you want to remove these files from within a bash script, you don't really need the function. Just add this line to your script (changing `mytexfile` to whatever your tex file is called):

```
find . -name "mytexfile*" | grep -vP '.tex$|.pdf$' | while read -r i; do rm "$i"; done
```

---

Finally, if you want to be able to do this for all tex files, whatever their name, use:

```
find . -name "*.tex" | sed 's/\.tex$//' | while read -r name; do 
    find . -name "$name"* | grep -vP '.tex$|.pdf$' | while read -r i; 
      do
        rm "$i"; 
      done;
done
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to define this function inside my `.sh` file instead of create another one? Second, to protect also `pdf` file I should define other function or is it possible to add this extension to the same function?

Comment: @Sigur By `.sh` you mean `bash.rc`? In any case no, no need for a new file just add this function to your existing bash settings file. As for the pdf, I already updated my question before seeing your comment :)

Comment: I mean, I am writing a file in my `/usr/bin` called `fastex.sh` to do many things to me. So, my question is: may I declare your function inside this file or I must to define it inside `bash.rc`. I am asking because I will share this script with other computers, so I would like to send only this script.

Comment: @Sigur I updated the question showing how you can use the command in a script.

Comment: perfect! Now it works exactly like I wish. Thanks so much.

Comment: All of these examples will break on files that contain spaces, and parsing `ls` output is [always wrong](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @jordanm Actually, none of these examples will break on names with spaces. Notice the quotes around `$name` and `$i` and the use of `read`. As you can see in the [official BASH FAQ](http://splike.com/wiki/Bash_Scripting_FAQ), the first question there recommends using a `while` loop with `read` specifically to deal with file names containing spaces. Still, you're right about `ls`. Changed to `find`.

Comment: @terdon, you are right, they break with files containing newlines, not spaces. Same with the updated answer, but I still consider it an improvement.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
rm *.{extension1,extension2,extension3}
```

Alternatively you can use:

```
shopt -s extglob
rm !(*.tex|*.pdf)
```

This will erase all but the files you want to keep, in this case the *.tex and *.pdf.

Comment: OP has explicitly requested a solution that does not involve specifying all of the relevant extensions...

Comment: @alemani, thanks. @jasonwryan, exactly. The problem is that the `$file.aux` always will be created but for example `$file.lof` won't. So, if I write all the extensions by hand, even if only one time, I could get some errors in case of non existing files. By the other hand, `rm $file.{* minus {.tex}}` will not produce an error, since that it includes the aux files.

Comment: @alemani, it does not work. I got the error 'couldn't remove $file.{xxx,xxx}'. File not found.

Comment: @Sigur It should work, like: `rm *.{aux,log,lof}` another method is to use: `shopt -s extglob` then `rm !(*.pdf|*.tex)` this way erases all but the files you want to keep.

Comment: @alemani, how to say that I want to delete only files named by `$file` and not all the files except pdf and tex?

Comment: @Sigur Well, you can use either `rm -f $file.{aux,log}` or `shopt -s extglob` then `rm !($file.pdf|$file.tex)`

Comment: `rm -f $file.{aux,log,toc,lof,lot,svn}` does not delete the files. But now I don't see any error message. About your second suggestion, that command will delete everything but `$file.pdf` and `$file.tex`? I don't want this, since I have other files, like `draws.eps`, for example, and I want to keep them.